# fzf not using `$FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND`

Tags: environment-variables, fish, fzf

I'm trying to get fzf to use `rg --files` as its command for searching, but can't seem to get it to use the `$FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` environment variable, as described in the docs.

I use `fish` as my shell, and in my `config.fish` I have `set FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` rg --files`. If I` echo $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND`in my shell, I get`rg --files`, so fish is definitely aware of it.

However, when I call `fzf` it doesn't use this command (for example, it shows gitignored files, such as build outputs etc, but if I just call `rg --files`, these aren't shown).

The man page for `fzf` says: "On *nix systems, fzf runs the command with `sh -c`, so make sure that it's POSIX-compliant". However, if I run `sh -c "echo $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND`, I get `rg --files`.

Clearly this env var isn't available in the right place, but I'm at a bit of a loss to know how to set it properly. Any help appreciated

Comment: Is `FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` exported as an environment variable? You can tell by running `env` and seeing if it's present in the output. You can export it via the `-x` flag to `set`, e.g. `set -gx FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND ...`

Comment: That fixed it, thanks :D

Comment: Also note that when you did `sh -c "echo $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND"`, that  interpolated the variable in Fish.  You would need `sh -c 'echo $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND'` or `sh -c "echo \$FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND"` to pass it to `sh` properly.  That was likely throwing you off a bit as well.  Now that you have it exported, it will show with either version.